# Remove two outliers in multiple regression

Tags: r

we've got a problem with removing two outliers from our dataset. The data is about an experiment with two independent and one dependent variable. We've exercised the multiple regression and analyzed the "Normal Q-Q" plot. It showed us two outliers (10,46). Now we would like to remove those two cases, before rerunning the multiple regression without the outliers. 
We've already tried out various commands recommended in several R platforms but unfortunately nothing worked out.
We would be glad, if anyone of you had an idea that would help us solving our problem.
Thank You very much for helping.

Comment: Can you post the data using `dput`?  Can you post the code that works so far?

Comment: If you do a diagnostics plot of your linear model object, the outliers will likely be marked with row numbers. Also note that outlayer is what you make of it. Or are you having trouble removing the rows? `data[-c(3,5), ]` will remove rows 3 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Since no data was provided, I fabricated some:

```
> x <- data.frame(a = c(10, 12, 14, 6, 10, 8, 11, 9), b = c(1, 2, 3, 24, 4, 1, 2, 4),
c = c(2, 1, 3, 6, 3, 4, 2, 48))
> x
   a  b  c
1 10  1  2
2 12  2  1
3 14  3  3
4  6 24  6
5 10  4  3
6  8  1  4
7 11  2  2
8  9  4 48
```

If the 4th case in column `x$b` and the 8th case in column `x$c` are outliers:

```
> x1 <- x[-c(4, 8), ]
> x1
   a b c
1 10 1 2
2 12 2 1
3 14 3 3
5 10 4 3
6  8 1 4
7 11 2 2
```

Is this what you need?